# Java script return false value

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net

When i try to run javascript using c# i got value **001-3undefined** instead of **001-3**

here is my c# code

`SalesReturn = "javascript:returnSale('&itemcode=" & dr_shop(0) & "&csid=" & csid & "')"`

javascript

`function returnSale(itemcode, csid) {
    mwindow = window.open("SaleReturnDetail.aspx?" + itemcode + csid , "SalesReturn", "height=225,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no")
    mwindow.moveTo(100, 150);
    }`

get value using request.querystring

`itemcode = Request.QueryString("itemcode")
 csid = Request.QueryString("csid")`

I got true value of itemcode but wrong csid value

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value to the function `returnSale` as a single value, so only the itemcode is being passed.

Try changing it to `returnSale('&itemcode=" & dr_shop(0) & "','&csid=" & csid & "')"`.

For readability you could change the function to;

```
SalesReturn = "javascript:returnSale('" & dr_shop(0) & "','" & csid & "')"

function returnSale(itemcode, csid) { 
    var mwindow;
    mwindow = window.open("SaleReturnDetail.aspx?itemcode=" + itemcode + "&csid=" + csid , "SalesReturn", "height=225,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no"); 
    mwindow.moveTo(100, 150); 
}
```